# Why im not able to change width of slide navbar background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so there is my navbar code. I want to make black background on menu while slide down from the top a bit shorter, can i do this ? I have tried to do something in css with whidth of .shrink class but it changed nothing. Also could you suggest me how can i change the place of logo in navbar while sliding down ? I will show you in pictures how i want it to look like.

https://ibb.co/cCh08RD - here is the pic, so placeholder is where the logo is in navbar. I want it to go lower while sliding like i tried to draw it and in the place of logo i want to display menu pic - something like this 3 lines. Also i tired to draw how width i would like it to be.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').addClass('shrink');

    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
```

```css
.background {
    background-image: url('../images/img1-header.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
}
#siteNav {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.shrink {
    background: rgba(32, 32, 32);
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
}
.shrink .logo {
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: flex;
    height: 38px;
}
#siteNav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
#siteNav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fafafa;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#siteNav ul li a {
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #000000;
}
#siteNav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Homenaje', sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 58px;
    padding-top: 130px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

header h1 a {
    color: #383838;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
            <nav id="siteNav">
                <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/40" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#mission">MISSION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <header>
                <div>
                    <h1>aaaaaaa <br><a>aaaaaaaaa</a></br>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it works for me. It changes the background of the nav on scroll.

In your embedded code I see the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

That's happening because you do not have jQuery referenced/included in your HTML document.

For the nav going a bit down on scroll, just add a margin-top on it.

For the image/logo re-positioning on scroll, you can re-position it with position:absolute (and 'pluck it out' of the document flow) if you want to leave the nav links as they are, and then move it around as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function sticktothetop() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var top = $('#stick-here').offset().top;
    if (window_top > top) {
        $('#stickThis').addClass('stick');
        $('#stick-here').height($('#stickThis').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#stickThis').removeClass('stick');
        $('#stick-here').height(0);
    }
}
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticktothetop);
    sticktothetop();
});
```

```css
#stickThis {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#stickThis.stick {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stick-here"></div>
<div id="stickThis">Sticky note</div>
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
lorem <br />
```